# Moving a File from Machine to Container Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I'm having an issue with Docker right now (Windows 7) and would greatly appreciate any insight. I set up a container in docker named `tf_files/starwars` and wanted to put a file into this container but I get this error:

> missing destination file operation after"
>   C:\Users\Brian\Downloads\darthvader

I have tried adding quotation marks, but to no avail. I would greatly appreciate any help on this as I have been trying to figure out how to add this file from my computer to this container for several hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know, to add a file into your container you can do this in 2 ways.

You either pre-bake the file into the `docker image` by using the `COPY` syntax in your `Dockerfile`.

**See:** https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy

Alternatively, you can mount the volume of your container to the host.

**Example:**
`docker run -v c:\<path>:c:\<container path>`

Where `c:\path` will be the directory on your windows machine and `container_path` is the directory your container will see the files from your host machine.

As such, whatever files you put in the `C:\path` area from your host, will also be visible within the container.

**See:**
https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume

Comment: How would I input that with the information I have. I am now getting that it's I need at least one argument. This is what I wrote: docker run -v C:\Users\Brian\Downloads\darthvader:c:\<tf_files>

Comment: The `docker run` command is about creating a `container` from a `docker image` so essentially you want to do `docker run -v blah:blah NAME_OF_YOUR_IMAGE`.

Comment: I really appreciate this. I have an existing container so is there a way to put a file of images in a container that already exists in windows?

Comment: @BrianAquino so I suppose recreating the container is not an option here? :(

Comment: @BrianAquino I haven't done this before but you can try doing `docker cp IMAGE_FILE.XYZ my_container_name:c:\<tf_files>` docker `cp` is suppose to allow you to copy files between your local file system into a running docker container

Comment: `docker run` both creates a container from an image using the arguments provided and then starts that container; you cannot alter the settings after the container is created. But, if you have a container, you have an image. If you have an image, you can create a new container from that image with new settings - a different volume mount. Good if you need to change the files easily or frequently. You can also create a derived image that has the files baked in, so that every container created from that image will have those files - good if you don't need to change the files often.